# When upload photo, Error: can't set header after they are sent,

Tags: node.js, axios

I Tried to upload photo through an api, this api isconsuming another api using axios but when i upload using this, it giving error:

Error: can't set header after they are sent,

when I debugged res.status after axios process throwing error to the catch block

Do I miss something, here's the code :

```
upload: async (req, res) => {
    const { subscriberId } = req.query;
    const file = req.file;

    if (!file) {
      return res
        .status(httpStatus.forbidden)
        .json({
          message: 'No File  Found'
        });
    }

    try {
      const form = new FormData();
      // console.log(form);
      form.append('file', 
        file.buffer,
        file.originalname
      );

      await axios.post(`${config.get('UPLOAD_PHOTO')}?subscriberId=${subscriberId}`, form, 
        {
          headers: {
            'api-key': `${config.get('API_KEY_CORE_SERVICE')}`,
            'Request-Id': req.requestId,
            'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // console.log(error.response.data)
          res.status(httpStatus.internalServerError).json({
            success: false,
            message: error.message,
            code: errorCodes.internalServerError
          });
        });

      return res.status(httpStatus.ok).json({
        success: true,
        status: httpStatus.ok,
        message: 'Successfully Upload Photo',
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(e.statusCode || httpStatus.internalServerError).json({
        success: false,
        message: (e.error && e.error.message) || e.message || e,
        code: errorCodes.internalServerError
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove this

```
        .catch((error) => {
          // console.log(error.response.data)
          res.status(httpStatus.internalServerError).json({
            success: false,
            message: error.message,
            code: errorCodes.internalServerError
          });
        });
```

You already have a try catch in place that basically does the same when this rejects/throws

```
await axios.post(`${config.get('UPLOAD_PHOTO')}?subscriberId=${subscriberId}`, form, 
        {
          headers: {
            'api-key': `${config.get('API_KEY_CORE_SERVICE')}`,
            'Request-Id': req.requestId,
            'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`
          }
        })
```